# sql statement single quote double quote - Either BOF or EOF is true

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, ado

Can you please help me with my sql statement? both studentID and password are text. 
I thought I figured out the single quote and double quote but apparently not as i am getting the error " Either BOF or EOF is True, or the current record has been deleted. Requested operation requires a current record ".

There is records in my table members.

```
var mycon;
mycon = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection");
var myrec ;
myrec= new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset"); 
mycon.Open("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data  Source=C:\\Database2.mdb");

var txtpassword = Request.QueryString("txtpassword");
var txtuserID = parseInt (Request.QueryString("txtuserID"));

var sql;
sql = "SELECT * FROM Members WHERE StudentID='"+txtuserID+"'AND  Password='"+txtpassword+"'";  

myrec.Open (sql, mycon);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax looks incorrect as you do not have a space between the `txtuserID` value and your `and` in your `sql` var. It should look like this

```
"SELECT * FROM Members WHERE StudentID = '"+txtuserID+"' AND  Password 
='"+txtpassword+"'";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
txtuserID = parseInt (Request.QueryString("txtuserID"));
```

You are parsing the `txtuserID` to an `INT`.
You should not put it in quotes, so you could change your `SQL` to:

```
"SELECT * FROM Members WHERE StudentID= "+txtuserID+" AND  Password='"+txtpassword+"'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but in:

> var sql;
>
> sql = "SELECT * FROM Members WHERE StudentID='"+txtuserID+"'AND  Password='"+txtpassword+"'";

The SQL statement in the text isn't finished with a ";".